# Xamarin Android service doesn't start until after InitializeComponent is complete

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm trying to start an Android service that needs to run before InitializeComponent in a Xamarin.Forms app. I start the service before InitializeComponent in code but stepping through it in the debugger reveals that the service doesn't actually start until InitializeComponent is complete. I can't have this because InitializeComponent triggers OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged and I need my service to start before the code in OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged is executed.

I tried putting the code to start the service in OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged but the same thing happened. Any ideas to have it run first or to prevent OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged from running as a result of InitializeComponent?

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        #if __ANDROID__
        //Launch Android background service if not running
        if (BackgroundService.isRunning == false)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(BackgroundService));
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartService(intent);
        }
        #endif

        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

Comment: @SushiHangover No dice. Service doesn't start until MainPage is Initialized.

Comment: Starting an Android Service is NOT a synchronous call, the best way would be to create a bounded service and provide the user with a "busy" indictor while you wait for your service to start providing the info that you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/bound-services